# How can I get datetime today date from C# with format 'dd-MMM-yy'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to get today date from C# and I am using this line of code:

```
 string result = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
```

The code is working fine on my localhost, but when I publish it to a Windows Server, it always returns this format of date:

```
28-juil.-22
```

But it should be like this `28-jul-22`

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given in the answer. To get more date time examples and information, you could refer to [DateTime.Now Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-6.0) and [DateTimeOffset.Now Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.now?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *Invariant culture* when formatting DateTime string:

```
string result = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For further and more detailed information about what is and how *Invariant culture* works please refer to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0